# Add leading zeros left and right of dash

Tags: c#, .net

I have an input string, with numeric digits separated by a hyphen. I need the left side to be exactly 5 digits. If it is less, then add leading zeros. The right side needs to be 4 digits. Any less, add leading zeros.

For example:

```
0002-800 -> 00002-0800
0001-0800 -> 00001-0800
12345-220 -> 12345-0220
```

Would the best approach be to split the string on the - character and then use the PadLeft function?

Comment: You already solved this yourself: (1) split on "-" (`string.Split`), (2) PadLeft the left part, (3) PadLeft the right part, (4) concatenate (`+`). If you want, you can combine (2), (3) and (4) into a single line of code. Where exactly do you need help?

Comment: `String.Join("-", str.Split('-').Select((x, pos) => x.PadLeft(5 - pos, '0').Trim()).ToArray())`

Comment: @haim770: The left and the right side have different lengths (5 vs 4 digits). Also: Don't spoil! ;-)

Comment: @Heinzi - yeah I guess typing it out made me think of a solution - maybe I should have coded it and sent for StackExcahnge code review - it was more could I do something with Regex - but maybe it is better to keep the code clean and more readable

Comment: @Heinzi, I took it into account

Comment: @haim770: Oh, indeed! My apologies.

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat: Hm.. you *could* use format strings (`$"{a:00000}-{b:0000}"`), which looks quite elegant, but then you'd have to parse those substrings into integers first. For splitting, string.Split is much easier than a regex in this particular case.

Comment: @haim770 - could you add your one liner as an answer I can accept and include and explanation of what the Select projection is doing?  and could that Select Project easily be changed if I needed to pad left to be 8 digits and on left and 3 digits on right etc or any other combination

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat, The `5 - pos` expression I used, assumed some correlation between the portion and its desired length. If it's no longer the case and the length of each is arbitrary, you'd have to map it explicitly somehow. For example, using `new Dictionary<int, int>()` where the key is the portion number and the value is the expected length.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the left side to be exactly 5 digits. If it is less, then add
> leading zeros. The right side needs to be 4 digits. Any less, add
> leading zeros.
>
> and could that Select Project easily be changed if I needed to pad
> left to be 8 digits and on left and 3 digits on right etc or any other
> combination

Written generically:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String input = "12345-12";
    String output = PadColumns(input, '-', '0', new int[] {8,3});
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
}

private String PadColumns(String input, char delimiter, char paddingChar, int[] columnWidths)
{
    String[] values = input.Split(new char[] {delimiter});
    for(int i=0; i<values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i<columnWidths.Length)
        {
            values[i] = values[i].PadLeft(columnWidths[i], paddingChar);
        }
    }
    return String.Join(delimiter.ToString(), values);
}
```

You could turn that code into an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) if you use it a lot.